# FLUTTER: ERROR TO SEND HTTP POST REQUEST USING A TEXT FIELD AND RAISED BUTTON

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart, qr-code

I have a FLUTTER problem that I couldn't solve.

Scenario:
1. Implement a QR reader application.
2. The app, read the QR code
3. When you read the QR code, you redirect me to a user's detail page

Problem: 
I want to edit that person's data, that's why place a TexFormField, valid fields, but when I call
FUTURE function to send the parameters by post, transforming the body in a JSON so that my server detects it, the button DOES NOTHING.

This is  My code

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
       child : Text("Escanea el codigo QR ", style: TextStyle(fontSize:  25.0),)
     ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(

       onPressed:  obtenerValorQR,
        child: Icon(Icons.settings_overscan,),
        backgroundColor:Color(0xFF56AB2F)

      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
```

---------------------------LOGIC -------------------------

```
Future obtenerValorQR()
         async{
                    _scantemp= await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode("#004297", "salir", true);
                    setState(() {
                      value=_scantemp;

                });
                if (value == null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, QrPageRoute);

                } else {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePageRoute, arguments: value);
                }   
            }
```

### 2. App read QR code

```
   Widget _infoPerfilUsuario(BuildContext context , index  ){
```

```
        return Container(
          height: 120.0,
          child: Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: 
                    NetworkImage(widget.usuarios[index].urlFoto), radius:  30.0,),
                    title: Text("Nombre: ${widget.usuarios[index].nombres}"),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Apellidos: ${widget.usuarios[index].apellidos}"),
                        Text("Zona: ${widget.usuarios[index].territorio}")
                      ],
                    ),   
                 ),
               )
           ),
        );
      }
```

3. QR DETAIL

   ### [image: QR MY PROFILE DETAIL]

### 4. I WANT TO OTHER PARAMETERS IN DETAILPAGE FOR EXAMPLE " PESO" BUT TH RAISED BUTTON DONT COMPILE THE CODE

[image: COMPLETE DETAIL PAGE]

5. Code where I send the "peso" parameter that I implement, but does not do what I am looking for.

   widget _botonesAcciones(BuildContext context ,  int index ){
               return Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                 children: [
                   RaisedButton(child: Text("SAVE "), color: Colors.green,
                   onPressed: () {
                           final form = formKey.currentState;
                           if(form.validate())  {
                           _sendData( context ,  index );
                           Navigator.pushNamed(context, QrPageRoute);
                         }
                       }
                   ),
                 ],
               );
             }

### I IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION IF THE FIELD IS VALIDATED, I just want the data to be sent, I don't want the response body returned, just send the data to my DataBase

Future <void> _sendData (BuildContext context ,  int index ) async {

    final url = Uri.https( _url,'/searchdata.php');
       await http.post(url,

        body: json.encode({
          "id"   : "${widget.usuarios[index].idUsuarioMobile}",
          "peso" : peso
        }),
      );

  }

Something is wrong?
 I think my mistake is in the sendData () function

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solucion is simple:

```
void _sendData(BuildContext context ,  int index ) {

       var url = Uri.https( _url,'/updatePuntos.php');
       http.post(url,

        body: json.encode({
          "id"   : "${widget.usuarios[index].idUsuarioMobile}",
          "peso" : peso
        }),
      );
```

Looking for me econtre, the answer to my question, was something as simple as returning a void method and sending the data to the server. You should use,

```
body: json.encode
```

it will make your life easier.